Sending a local file to an API in Node JS
I am trying to send a local file to an API. There is no error in the code but the file on the remote server is corrupted. What am I doing wrong? The file is present in my directory. It is an 82 kb pdf file but in remote server it shows 149kb file and is unreadable.
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', fs.createReadStream("test.pdf") );
    data.append('profile', 'xyz');
    data.append('filename', "test.pdf");
    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: 'https://api.xyz.com/uploads',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Bearer xyz`, 
            'Content-Type': `application/pdf`
        },
        data : data
      };
      axios.request(config)
      .then((response) => {
       // log(response)
        res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        res.status(200).send({"result":"success"}).end()
      }).catch((error) => {
        log(error);
        res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        res.status(200).send({"result":"fail"}).end()
      });

I have also tried this with below header but with no luck.
'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`


I found out that I had not added a require. This fixed the issue:
const FormData = require("form-data");

